# Why columns swapper does not work?

Tags: jquery

I try to swap two columns. This should replace *div#navigace* for *div#text*. The selectors variable should enable to swap pairs of elements.

```
var selectors = "div#navigace;div#text"
selectors = selectors.split(";");
    var searches = [];
    var targets = [];
    for ( var k in selectors )
      {
      if ( (k % 2) != 0 )
        searches.push(selectors[k]);
      else
        targets.push(selectors[k]);      
      }

    for ( var k in searches )
      {
      var cloned = $(searches[k]).clone(true); // clone col.#1
      $(searches[k]).replaceWith($(targets[k])); // reúůace col.#1 with col #2
      $(targets[k]).replaceWith(cloned); // replace col. #2 with clone of #1
      }
```

This is the [site](https://www.jakpsatweb.cz/) where the columns are present, I inject the code from Firefox webextensions. In short:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="jquery_3.0.0" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="my_code_comes_here.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>

<html>
<body>
<div id="text">

<div class="velke">
    <h1>How to write www</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div id="navigace">
<h3>Favourites:</h3>
</div>

<div id="hlavicka">
</div>

<div id="hrasek"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

What happens: left column disappears, right columns stayed on place.

What should happen: left column should display on the right side, right column on the left side. In the case of the short html above, the upper div should be place at bottom the bottom should be place upwards.

Edit:
[Live example](http://kod.djpw.cz/cwac)

Comment: can you show the relevant html?

Comment: I have updated the question. Added html with script simulating JQuery library injection and the JS code injection. I have added description what it does and what it should do.

Comment: Live example added http://kod.djpw.cz/cwac

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems I found.

1) `selectors.split(";");` returns a new array, it does not modify the original string variable. So you need to do either:

```
var selectors = "div#navigace;div#text".split(';');
```

or

```
var selectors = "div#navigace;div#text";
selectors = selectors.split(";");
```

The way your code is not, it is just looping through each letter of the string `div#navigace`, not exactly ideal.

2) You are trying to do jQuery operations, but jQuery doesn't actually exist on the page. Either put jQuery on the page, or switch to native DOM methods.

3) If you do use jQuery, you can't switch them with each other. For example, let's say you have two boxes with the letters A and B on them. And you want to switch them. And then you say "let's put A where B is, and then B where A is". A will move to where B was, but B will not move. You want to do it where A *was*. However, your code is telling it to replace the box that actually replaced another box, therefore it won't work as intended. To remedy this, we store both of them in variables, clone them, then swap.

```
for ( var k in searches )
{
  var search = $(searches[k]);
  var target = $(targets[k]);
  var clonedSearch = search.clone(true); // clone col.#1
  var clonedTarget = target.clone(true); // clone col.#2

  search.replaceWith(clonedTarget); // reúůace col.#1 with col #2
  target.replaceWith(clonedSearch); // replace col. #2 with clone of #1
}
```

**Problem**: The code above will cause it to work, the positions will switch in the DOM. However, their actual positioning is controlled via CSS. So really, even when the code you have is made to work perfectly, they will still look exactly the same.
*If* you want to change their positions visually, you don't even need to move the DOM. You can just do this:

```
#navigace {
   position: absolute;
   top: 150px;
   left: 10px;
   width: 25%;
}
#text {
   margin: 150px 3% 0px 27vw
   width: 68.5%;
}
```

Maybe you want it switched only in the DOM and you don't care about how it looks visually, but just in case, figured I'd cover all the bases.

Comment: JQuery is connected via my Firefox extension which uses webextension. This injects the jquery library just like I would include the jquery library in the page. It injects the JS code too. I guess I will add this to the html to make it more clear.

Comment: @user1141649 Nicely done, I did a little more digging and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think the problem is in absolute positioning? It would be possible to obtain the positions of left & top using .offset method and to replace these values, +to add absolute positioning to both wrappers.

Comment: I've tried this example: http://kod.djpw.cz/dwac but it contains some error with } . IDK I was not able to remove the error

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks to Amleonard to show me that this problem cannot be solved with replacing of the DOM objects. I choosed the CSS solution:

```
var selectors = "div#navigace;div#text"
selectors = selectors.split(";");    var searches = [];
var targets = [];
for ( var k in selectors )
      {
      if ( (k % 2) == 0 )
        searches.push(selectors[k]);
      else
        targets.push(selectors[k]);      
      }

for ( var k in searches )
   {
   var search = $(searches[k]);
   var target = $(targets[k]);
   var offset_search = search.offset();
   var offset_target = target.offset();
   search.css({
           'position' : 'absolute',
           'left' : offset_target.left + 'px',
           'top' : offset_target.top + 'px'
      });
   target.css({
           'position' : 'absolute',
           'left' : offset_search.left + 'px',
           'top' : offset_search.top + 'px'
      });
}
```

Works great (at least when there is not right: attribute).